# google actions sdk: get project id of requesting webhook

Tags: actions-on-google

I am creating an action using actions sdk and the fulfilment URL is a google cloud functions. I plan to use the same fulfilment webhook for different actions by sending some parameter. e.g. one action may be: `https:// .../action1` while the second may be: `https://.../action2`. Is there a way I can get the url in the NodeJS webhook.

The NodeJS function has the export in the form:
`exports.funcname = functions.https.onRequest(app);`
where app is an actionssdk object

I know that there is a way to verify whether the request is from a particular google actions project using:

`const app = actionssdk({verification: 'nodejs-cloud-test-project-1234'});`

(source:https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/verify-requests)

However, for my use-case I would need to know which actions project has made the request or access the called url, so that I can customise the response. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The project_id is included in the [`session`](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent) string in every webhook request, you could parse that with a simple regex.

Comment: Thanks @gmoulau. The link is to a DialogFlow API. Is this supported in actionssdk?

Comment: I tried to get the request using the actions-on-google-nodejs library but there seems no way to get the webhook URL or session. Could you please suggest the object in the `conv` that has the url or project. Reason I ask even the URL is that I could send the project-id as a param in the webhook request and then use it to verify if required. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, that was a misunderstanding on my part, I thought you were using Dialogflow. The [Conversation Webhook](https://developers.google.com/actions/build/json/conversation-webhook-json) protocol does not seem to include the project_id anywhere in its requests, so I'm afraid you are out of luck here.

Comment: I did figure out a way using the authorization string that it passes via the express middleware. I shared it in the github repository issue (https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/issues/291#issuecomment-469995196) as a work-around for now. Thanks @gmolau. Your suggestion will help if I use dialogflow in some project.